# Joomla2.5 k2 rss feed url

Tags: joomla, rss

I have joomla 2.5 site.I am using k2 component.Eack K2 category give one url for feed url.
example

My_site_Url/index.php/component/k2/itemlist/category/26-us.feed

I can get one feed Url for one category.
How can get all category? Please advice me.
Sorry for my english.
Thank All friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a professional solution to create RSS Feed for Joomla K2 by obRSS with K2 at [Joomla K2 RSS Feed Creator](http://foobla.com/joomla/obrss)

Comment: We're not big fans of sneaky self-promotion here, particularly considering it looks like you joined just to post this.  Care to be more explicit about your relationship with foobla.com?

Comment: I'm new here. IMOH, I would rather offer the questioner a working-solution than leave the question as unanswered.